# Why does this template metafunction involving std::enable_if yield undesired results?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a type trait

```
template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct is_binary_function : std::false_type {};
```

and its specialization

```
template <typename function_t>
struct is_binary_function<function_t,
                          std::enable_if_t<
                              !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::result_t> &&
                              !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::parameter1_t> &&
                              !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::parameter2_t> &&
                              function_t::isBinaryCallable
                              , function_t>
        > : std::true_type {};
```

I am trying to identify classes, that have the public type definitions `result_t`, `parameter1_t`, and `parameter2_t`, as well as a static constant `isBinaryCallable` with the value true.

However, the following code does not output what I expect:

```
struct f {
    using result_t = float;

    using parameter1_t = float;
    using parameter2_t = float;

    static constexpr bool isBinaryCallable = true;
};


int main() {
    using function_t = f;

    std::cout << is_binary_function<f>::value << '\n'; //Error: outputs false, instead of true
    std::cout << std::is_void_v<function_t::result_t> << '\n'; //false, as expected
    std::cout << std::is_void_v<function_t::parameter1_t> << '\n'; //false, as expected
    std::cout << std::is_void_v<function_t::parameter2_t> << '\n'; //false, as expected
    std::cout << function_t::isBinaryCallable << '\n'; //true, as expected
    std::cout << (!std::is_void_v<typename function_t::result_t> &&
        !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::parameter1_t> &&
        !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::parameter2_t> &&
        function_t::isBinaryCallable) << '\n'; // true, as expected.
}
```

I guess my use of the metafunction pattern is flawed, but I can't figure out what I did wrong.

**Why does the above metafunction not work as expected?**

I am using Visual Studio 2017, set to the C++ 17 Standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
std::enable_if_t<
                          !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::result_t> &&
                          !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::parameter1_t> &&
                          !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::parameter2_t> &&
                          function_t::isBinaryCallable
                          , function_t>
```

should be

```
std::enable_if_t<
                          !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::result_t> &&
                          !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::parameter1_t> &&
                          !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::parameter2_t> &&
                          function_t::isBinaryCallable
                          , void>
```

or

```
std::enable_if_t<
                          !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::result_t> &&
                          !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::parameter1_t> &&
                          !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::parameter2_t> &&
                          function_t::isBinaryCallable>
```

because `is_binary_function<f>::value` is `is_binary_function<f, void>::value` as specified in your primary template specialization of `is_binary_function` (the second argument defaults to `void`), meanwhile

```
std::enable_if_t<
                          !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::result_t> &&
                          !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::parameter1_t> &&
                          !std::is_void_v<typename function_t::parameter2_t> &&
                          function_t::isBinaryCallable
                          , function_t>
```

when passed `function_t` as `f` is `f`, not `void`.  So it fails to match.

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: This does solve the issue, thanks for the great and quick explanation.